# How to display php script output in column wise based on the match in if statement

Tags: php, html

I have the following PHP code which will print the server names with different color codes likes Green-Ok,Yellow-warning,Red-critical,Orange-unknown.

```
foreach ($status->members_with_state as $server) {

    if ($server[1] == 0) {

            $state = "OK";

            echo "Server: <font color=\"green\">$server[0]</font><br />";

    } elseif ($server[1] == 2) {

            $state = "WARNING";

            echo "Server: <font color=\"yellow\">$server[0]</font><br />";

    } elseif ($server[1] == 1) {

            $state = "CRITICAL";

            echo "Server: <font color=\"red\">$server[0]</font><br />";

    } elseif ($server[1] == 3) {

            $state = "UNKNOWN";
            echo "Server: <font color=\"orange\">$server[0]</font><br />";
      }
```

}

ISSUE:

All the servers are printed in one big list in a single column.
Could you please suggest required modifications in code to get the server names column wise like in attached screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEJ8G.png)

Comment: Seems like you are looking for the html `<table>` element?

Comment: y are u using <br>?

Comment: First, do you want it in a tabular format? What exactly do you want it to look like? Show your desired format. Take a screenshot, explain it here..do anything. You can't expect people to help you out if you don't give us enough details about your problem....

Comment: Remove the BR Tag from the code

Comment: Hi all, ok , i will update my question with desired format.

Comment: if I am removing br, output is coming in single horizontal line

Comment: I have added the link to the desired output